# Increasing php memory usage issue

Tags: php, centos, memory-limit

I'm currently running CentOS 6.5 64bit with 12gb RAM and im trying to allocate 1.5gb of memory in a php script. 
Ive tried changing php.ini memory_limit to 2048M and adding the line ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M'); into my code. I tried "-1" in both places and it still gives me this line

**Fatal error:** Out of memory (allocated 262144) (tried to allocate 1543346177 bytes) in /hom...

and here is my server memory usage

```
         total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
         11870       1034      10836          0         72        440
```

php code where the error happens (3 line)

```
$fileSize = filesize($imgName);
$fh = fopen($imgName, 'rb');
$imgData = fread($fh, $fileSize);
fclose($fh);
```

Does anyone has solution about this problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: is your php file in question the one creating this massive memory usage? maybe you could post that script too

Comment: Ive added the code to the question

Comment: so, what is the value of `$filesize`?